# How to open a new tab using an extension and selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

how can I press a combination of buttons using selenium in chrome?
I have an extension which opens a new tab by pressing control + shift + x but how can I use the shortcut of this extension in selenium?
I have tested many things but they didnt work for me.

Thx for every answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

It send series of key codes to the body element of the webpage.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, Keys.LEFT_SHIFT, "x");
```

Alternative is `Actions`

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action seriesOfActions = builder
        .keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
        .keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT)
        .sendKeys("x")
        .build();

seriesOfActions.perform();
```

Comment: added alternative

Comment: hmm thank you, but I just tried it and it just does not open the tab, i dont even get an error message :/

Comment: can you give a website link?

Comment: do you mean for the plugin or what? ^^

Comment: okay wait a second, you ask 'how can I press a combination of buttons using selenium in chrome?' This two solution i provider are working in-real. If you wish to use selenium to automate an 3rd party app, you are in wrong direction. Please explain agian what exactly you want.

Comment: so i am just testing to send myself emails but i can not login into 2 emails from the same provider in one window so i donwloaded the extension called "SessionBox" now i can manually open another tab in which i can sign into the second account by pressing ctrl+shift+x and now i want to do that by using selenium instead of doing it manually

Comment: what you are trying to do its not related to selenium at all, the key combinations you send are intercepted from the extension!

Comment: okay, you need to know i am an absolute beginner, so im sorry if i seem a little stupid, but i thought if i manually press ctrl+shift+x and a new tab opens; shouldnt selenium also open a new tab if it hits ctrl+shift+x? o.0

Comment: i have a extension that interecept ctrl + shift + x when i press this combination it opens his window, for new tab keychord is different. Info: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en